# Date::DAYNAMES doesn't offer a proper :select :collection on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

When I try to create a dropdown from `Date::DAYNAMES` on my Mac and my work Windows 7 machine, I get a select box with an index and the day name. However, when I move it to my Netbook (Windows 7), all I get is the first letter of the day name despite having the same exact code. Any ideas how to fix it?

Selected `ActiveAdmin` registration code:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Assessment do
  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :start_dow, :as => :select,
                                 :collection => Date::DAYNAMES.each_with_index
    end
    f.buttons
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why it worked sometimes in the past, but I switched it to:

```
f.input :start_dow, as => :select,
                          :collection => Date::DAYNAMES.each_with_index.to_a
```

Now it seems to work just fine on all the platforms I've used for testing so far. Perhaps it was different versions of ruby that were the issue? I've recently found that I've been using different versions…